# Script Editor shows Error: No Error in JavaScript code for sending email

Tags: macos, script, javascript-automation

I am trying to learn how to create automation scripts in macOS with the JavaScript language. I was trying to figure out how to make a script that would send an email. Everything seemed to be going fine until I got an error message that said `Error on line 12: Error: No error.` I've searched the web and haven't found any other occurrences like this.

[image: Script Editor error message popup]

This is the code that I ran:

```
var currentApp = Application.currentApplication();
currentApp.includeStandardAdditions = true;
var Mail = Application('Mail');

var messageName = Mail.OutgoingMessage();

messageName.sender = 'email@example.com';
messageName.subject = 'Test';

Mail.send(messageName);
```

The error appears to be for the `Mail.send(messageName)` line.

Can anyone explain to me why I got this message and what I need to do to fix it? Is it just a bug with Script Editor?

Comment: Task failed successfully. Using JS syntax in AS is new to me.. What reference are you following? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50898354/applescript-mail-attachment-not-sending This is the same problem with different approach.

Comment: I am using the Script Editor dictionaries and documentation from the [Apple Developer](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/InterapplicationCommunication/RN-JavaScriptForAutomation/Articles/OSX10-11.html) site. There is a dropdown list in the dictionary to select between AppleScript, JavaScript, and Objective-C.

Comment: [Cannot concatenate text in JXA](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/286889/cannot-concatenate-text-in-jxa) See if this is helpful. goal is sending email there too